# ssh: connect to host git.ionicjs.com port 22: Connection timed out

Tags: git, github, ionic-framework, ssh, ionic3

I'm working on an Ionic application, I started by creating a new project via Ionic Dashboard. Later I connected my apllication using this command : `ionic start --pro-id my-id`.

But when I try to push my code up to the dashboard using the following command : `git push ionic master` I Recieved this error :

```
ssh: connect to host git.ionicjs.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried to use **http** protocol instead of **ssh** in the config file, following th steps below :

1. `git config --local -e`
2. `url = git@git.ionicjs.com/usename/myproject.git`
3. `url = https://git.ionicjs.com/usename/myproject.git`

But stil have this issue : `fatal: unable to access 'https://git.ionicjs.com:username/myproject.git/': Port number ended with 'b'`

Any idea to resolve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem with ssh is that `git.ionicjs.com` has 2 different IP addresses. One of them (35.162.243.99) has port 22 open and the other (35.162.243.97) doesn't. I recommend to report the problem to ionicjs.com.
2. The correct syntax for HTTP URL is `https://git.ionicjs.com/username/myproject.git`, not `https://git.ionicjs.com:username/myproject.git/`.